# How to change current JRE on mac?

Tags: mac, command-line, unix, java

I would like to change the current JRE from `Version 10.0.1` to some previous versions like 1.8 for instance. At the moment Im confused about my current setting. Basically, Java Panel in `System Preferences` is telling me that my Java Version is `Version 10.0.1` which corresponds to:

```
 $ /Library/Internet\ Plug- Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

`java -version` was telling me that:

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

So, I tried to set different versions of my JDK in `.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_9_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v9)
export JAVA_10_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v10)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java9='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_9_HOME'
alias java10='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_10_HOME'
#default java8
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME
```

Where I set the default version to:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

However, that does not change the JRE.
I would like to have JRE and JDK the same version (1.8). How can I do that, since one JRE can be installed at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by "However, that does not change the JRE"?  It looks like your `java -version` command is showing the JRE you asked for.

Comment: Thats the `JRE` $ /Library/Internet\ Plug- Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
`java version "10.0.1"` 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Comment: Thats the `JDK` java -version
`java version "1.8.0_172"`
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: They are different